# Is it possible to write an angular-cli add-on without to hard code it in angular-cli

Tags: typescript, angular, build-process, ember-cli, angular-cli

I would like to write an add-on for a custom distribution process and use this command in a terminal. Is it possible without hard-code the command in the source of angular-cli?

I saw that the command "github-pages-deploy" is hard-coded in angular-cli/addon/ng2/index.js file.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that github pages deployments is within the Angular CLI itself, an example of implementing a deployment externally via an add-on can be found here: https://github.com/davideast/angular-cli-firebase-hosting

Comment: hanks for the answer, i studied the documentation but do not understand how can i access the angular2app tree within an angular-cli plugin. I would like to do some processing on the index.html file and export the result (new tree) into my angular2 app.